# What is the relation between Microsoft private cloud and azure?

Tags: azure

I installed Microsoft 2008 R2 and all software needed for Microsoft private cloud. It seems all I can offer to the user is a portal where he/she can "rent" virtual machines. All what I read about "Web-Role" and "Worker-Role" hasn't any relevance here.(?)

Is my assumption correct: I can only create a private cloud which offers IaaS(?). "Azure" is an application which runs on some Microsoft private cloud and offers PaaS.(?) "Azure" is a PaaS service I can use. But I can't start it on my own private cloud, because I cannot get the Azure software(?) Is that correct?

Comment: It think it would be best to migrate this question to ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

Private Cloud in the Microsoft Context usually relates to System Center running a hypervisor (e.g. hyper-v) and using the in-built capability of System Center to spin up gallery images, gold templates and allow charge back (portal) etc. This is all done on-premises and not in the public cloud.

Microsoft has released an on-premises "sort of" Azure technology ["Windows Azure Services to Windows Server for Hosting Service Providers"](http://www.microsoft.com/hosting/en/us/services.aspx) that you can run too, but its meant for hosters running at scale to offer Windows Azure capability in an on-premises (hosted) environment, this currently supports Web Sites and IaaS (VM), not Cloud Services (Web/Worker Roles) and does not run in the public Cloud.

Windows Azure now offers, IaaS (WinSrv28R2, WinSrv2012, Linux etc.) and PaaS (Web/Worker Roles) and Windows Azure Web Sites that run in the public Cloud on data centers in North America, Europe and Asia that allow you to run at massive scale on a pay-per-use model offering full Public Cloud Platform to fulfill your I.T. needs.

HTH